# linux diff to only output filename and nothing else

Tags: linux, diff

I'm trying to get diff to output only the name of the modified files.
I tried to use the -q option but it's still giving me too much output :

What i get now is this :

```
files path/to/file1/file1 and path/to/file2/file2 are different
```

And i would like this :

```
path/to/file1/file1
```

Any ideas on how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the exit status of diff:

```
if ! diff -q file1 file2 >/dev/null; then echo file1; fi
```

Comment: +1, though that doesn't work with `diff -r`; you'd have to combine it with `find` to check each file in a huge list.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

`diff -q file1 file2 | cut -f2 -d' '`

Answer (score 1):

You can always pipe it to something else, such as:

```
# diff ... | sed 's/^files //;s/ and .*//;'
```

However, note that if you have a file with a literal " and " in it, then the above will cause a problem.  Generally I encourage people not to use spaces in file names anyway.  Yes you can do it, but yes it still causes problems.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Wes's answer:

```
echo "files path/to/file1/file1 and path/to/file2/file2 are different" | sed -e "s/^files //" -e "s/ and .*$//"
```

.

```
//output 
path/to/file1/file1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `cmp --silent` instead of `diff -q`. This sends nothing to stdout, so you only need to deal with the exit status.

For example:

```
file1=path/to/file1/file1; cmp --silent $file1 path/to/file2/file2 || echo $file1
```

The exit status of cmp is the same as diff (0 if inputs are the same and 1 if different).